# Giving each Google Distance Matrix result an id

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Distance Matrix https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/
to calculate some delivery charges. When it outputs the results in the for loop it puts them onto a new line each time, so I end up with :

```
1
25
26
1
```

Is it possible to store each result in a variable so I can call each individual result elsewhere in the code for some maths to work out costs etc, so.....

```
$result1
$result2
$result3
$result4
```

As later on I would like to do things like result1 * result3 = etc etc.

```
        <script>

          var map;
          var geocoder;
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          var markersArray = [];

          var base = new google.maps.LatLng(55.930385, -3.118425);
          var start = 'Greenwich, England';
          var destinationA = 'Stockholm, Sweden';
          var end = new google.maps.LatLng(55.930385, -3.118425);

          var destinationIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=D|FF0000|000000';
          var originIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=O|FFFF00|000000';

          function initialize() {
            var opts = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.53, 9.4),
              zoom: 10,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), opts);
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            calculateDistances();
          }

          function calculateDistances() {
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            service.getDistanceMatrix(
              {
                origins: [base],
                destinations: [start, end],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
              }, callback);
          }

          function callback(response, status) {
            if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
              alert('Error was: ' + status);
            } else {
              var origins = response.originAddresses;
              var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
              var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
              outputDiv.innerHTML = '<table border="1">';
              deleteOverlays();
              var stringArray = ['$runinPickup','$runinDestination'];
              var htmlString = '<table border="1">';
              for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
                var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                addMarker(origins[i], false);
                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                  addMarker(destinations[j], true);
                  htmlString += '<tr><td>'+stringArray[j]+'</td><td>' + results[j].distance.text +'</td></tr>';
                  outputDiv.innerHTML += '<tr><td>'+stringArray[j]+'</td><td>' + results[j].distance.text +'</td></tr>';
                }
              }
              htmlString += '</table>';
              // outputDiv.innerHTML += '</table>';
              outputDiv.innerHTML = htmlString;
              // alert(htmlString);
            }
          }

          function addMarker(location, isDestination) {
            var icon;
            if (isDestination) {
              icon = destinationIcon;
            } else {
              icon = originIcon;
            }
            geocoder.geocode({'address': location}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: results[0].geometry.location,
                  icon: icon
                });
                markersArray.push(marker);
              } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: '
                  + status);
              }
            });
          }

          function deleteOverlays() {
            if (markersArray) {
              for (i in markersArray) {
                markersArray[i].setMap(null);
              }
              markersArray.length = 0;
            }
          }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that shouldn't be too hard.  Where you output the value, e.g.

```
htmlString += '<tr><td>'+stringArray[j]+'</td><td>' + results[j].distance.text +'</td></tr>';
```

Simply add an additional line assigning that value into a variable.  I'd be inclined to add them into an array which you can loop over later.

```
arrResults.push(results[j].distance.text);
```

If you're confident you always know what each value will be, then you can simply refer to them like `arrResults[0] * arrResults[2]`

Comment: Sorry I added the wrong line for that one, it should be html += parseInt(elements[j].distance.text) + "<br />";

Comment: How do I add that into an array ?.

Comment: `array.push(parseInt(elements[j].distance.text));`